# How to ignore keyboardInterrupt Exception in a module and deal with it in higher level in winpexpet?

Tags: python, exception, pexpect, keyboardinterrupt

Hii all i'm trying to disable keyboard ctrl-c in my python console program in win7 x64.My script uses [winpexect](https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/wiki/Home) to run an external program which runs a few hours. i
ve already tried

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,signal.SIG_IGN)
```

it works before i ran into the winpexpect part, if winpexpect spawned process has started, then i press ctrl-c . the following error occurs.

```
  File "xxx.py", line 605, in myFunc
    i = thread.expect_list(cpl,timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.6-py2.7.egg\pexpect.py", line
 1325, in expect_list
    return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize
)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.6-py2.7.egg\pexpect.py", line
 1378, in expect_loop
    c = self.read_nonblocking (self.maxread, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.6-py2.7.egg\winpexpect.py", l
ine 955, in read_nonblocking
    handle, status, data = self.child_output.get(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\Queue.py", line 177, in get
    self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 358, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
IOError: [Errno 4] Interrupted function call
```

i checked winpexpect source, it catches this exception when scanning the output of the program, is there any way to tell it to ignore this exception and deal with it in my main python script ? ( have to change winpexpect code ?)

so the question in other words may be "How to ignore exception caught in a module and re-raise it, so outer code can catch it later ?"